# Find the minimum value in a map

Tags: erlang

I have a map organized as follows.Key is a simple term lets say an integer but the value is complex tuple {BB,CC,DD}. What is the best way to find the minimum CC in the map ? So far I have the following

```
-module(test).
-author("andre").

%% API
-export([init/0]).

init() ->
  TheMap = build(maps:new(), 20),
  io:format("Map: ~p~n", [TheMap]),
  AKey = hd(maps:keys(TheMap)),
  AValue = maps:get(AKey, TheMap),
  maps:fold(fun my_min/3, {AKey, AValue}, TheMap).

build(MyMap, Count) when Count == 0 ->
  MyMap;
build(MyMap, Count) ->
  NewMap = maps:put(Count, {random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100)}, MyMap),
  build(NewMap, Count - 1).

my_min(Key, {A,B,C}, {MinKey, {AA,BB,CC}}) ->
  if B < BB -> {Key, {A,B,C}};
     B >= BB -> {MinKey, {AA,BB,CC}}
  end.
```

My map is small so I am not too worried about the usage of AKey and AValue to find initial values for the fold, but I was wondering if there was a better way, or other data structure.

--
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is close to a good solution, but it can be improved. There's no need to dig out the first key and value to use an the initial value for the fold, since you can just pass an artificial value instead and make your fold function deal with it. Also, you can improve your use of pattern matching in function heads. Lastly, use `start` instead of `init` since that makes it easier to invoke when calling `erl` from the command line.

Here's an improved version:

```
-module(test).
-author("andre").

%% API
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    TheMap = build(maps:new(), 20),
    io:format("Map: ~p~n", [TheMap]),
    maps:fold(fun my_min/3, {undefined, undefined}, TheMap).

build(MyMap, 0) ->
    MyMap;
build(MyMap, Count) ->
    NewMap = maps:put(Count, {random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100)}, MyMap),
    build(NewMap, Count - 1).

my_min(Key, Value, {undefined, undefined}) ->
    {Key, Value};
my_min(Key, {_,B,_}=Value, {_, {_,BB,_}}) when B < BB ->
    {Key, Value};
my_min(_Key, _Value, Acc) ->
    Acc.
```

The `my_min/3` fold function has three clauses. The first matches the special start value `{undefined, undefined}` and returns as the new accumulator value whatever `{Key, Value}` it was passed. The benefit of this is not only that you avoid special processing before starting the fold, but also that if the map is empty, you'll get the special value `{undefined, undefined}` as the result and you can handle it accordingly. The second clause uses a guard to check if `B` of the value is less than the `BB` value in the fold accumulator, and if it is, return `{Key, Value}` as the new accumulator value. The final clause just returns the existing accumulator value, since this clause is called only for values greater than or equal to that in the existing accumulator.

You might also look into using a simple list of key/value tuples, since for a small number of elements it might outperform a map. If your measurements indicate you should use a list, a similar fold would work for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
-module(test).
-author("andre").

%% API
-export([init/0]).

init() ->
    TheMap = build(maps:new(), 24),
    io:format("Map: ~p~n", [TheMap]),
    List = maps:to_list(TheMap),
    io:format("List: ~p~n", [List]),

    Fun = fun({_, {_, V1, _}} = Element, {_, {_, V2, _}}) when V1 < V2 ->
      Element;
       (_, Res) ->
      Res
    end,

    Res = lists:foldl(Fun, hd(List),  tl(List)),
    io:format("Res: ~p~n", [Res]).


build(MyMap, Count) when Count == 0 ->
    MyMap;
build(MyMap, Count) ->
    NewMap = maps:put(Count, {random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100)}, MyMap),
    build(NewMap, Count - 1).
```

You can use [maps:to_list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#to_list-1) to convert the map to a list, then you can use [lists:foldl/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3) to calculate the minimun value.